# Django + Ajax Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to add an upvote button using ajax + django. Following [this example](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/ajax.html#add-a-like-button), I was able to set up the following, but nothing happens when I click "upvote". (runserver is not getting any requests)

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def upvote(request):
    recommendation = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        recommendation = request.GET['recommendation']

    if recommendation:
        recommendation.votes.up(user)

    return HttpResponse(upvotes)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^upvote/$', coreviews.upvote, name='upvote'),
```

**html**

```
<p><strong id="like_count">Vote Count: {{ recommendation.get_total_votes }}</strong> people like this category

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <button id="upvotes" data-recommendation="{{ recommendation }}" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
        Like
    </button>
    {% endif %}
</p>
```

**ajax.js**

```
$('#upvotes').click(function(){
    var recommendation;
    recommendation = $(this).attr("data-recommendation");
    $.get('/upvote/', {recommendation: recommendation}, function(data){
               $('#like_count').html(data);
               $('#upvote').hide();
    });
});
```

#### This is essentially what I'm trying to make the button do (works in python shell):

```
>>> import core.models as coremodels
>>> var1 = coremodels.Recommendation.objects.get(title="test5")
>>> var1.get_total_votes()
0
>>> var1.votes.up(user)
```

Comment: Did you try to see what's being called and the answer when you click on "Like"? You can use Charles, Chrome Developer tools, etc.